# проблема с установкой npm-пакетов

Tags: gulp, npm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не могу установить пакеты и запустить тоже, зацикливается на скачивании или выдает ошибку.Помогите прошу вас. Все перепробовал

Comment: Замените картинку нормальным текстом, это только улучшит читаемость вопроса.

Comment: А интернет в это время у вас нормально работает? Если да, попробуйте отключить на время загрузки антивирус и фаервол